# Do I need a ridge beam or is a ridge board adequate?

Tags: framing, roof

Working on a 10'x16' cabin design I plan to build this summer. The walls are 10' high. There is 6' loft on one end that is sitting on a double top plate of 2x4x8' walls to support the loft. On the other end there's a 32" storage ledge on top of the 2x4x10' walls.

I want to build cathedral ceilings (no rafter joists) Generally speaking without all of the information of load, environment, etc; Is the loft and the storage ledge enough to hold the walls together? or do I need a ridge beam?[image]

Comment: Do you expect the walls to bulge?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have less than 8 feet of unsupported wall, I don't believe you need a ridge beam. Many a garage has been built with hand-framed rafters spanning much more than 10 feet with only one or two rafter ties. You should see little to no movement.

One way to add peace of mind, though, would be to use short collar ties or gussets at the peak, even if just through that unsupported area.

By the way, you never really *need* a ridge board. The sheathing locks the rafters in place. Modern roofs rarely have them.

Comment: Interesting about not needing the ridge board. I understand the concept, but it seems like a _major pain_ to try to balance the rafters without one until the sheathing is up. I guess one could tack on temporary supports, but that seems like more work than necessary. Considering options as I've got a small addition to build soon...

Comment: Once they're nailed at the wall plate they don't move much. You measure them in when you lay sheathing _anyway_ to keep them straight, so....

Comment: I would think that they'd wobble/lean when nailed to the top plate and to each other without _some_ sort of bracing to keep them upright. I'll trust you on this, though. I definitely put bracing across my trusses when I built the garage to keep them from wobbling around before the sheathing went up, so I guess that's about the same thing. Thanks for the tip, I hadn't thought about that possibility.

Comment: You'd brace a 26 foot garage truss. You wouldn't worry a bit about a couple of 6 foot 2x4s. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you will have about 8' of cathedral ceiling beyond the loft and storage. You should add collar ties at least 32" apart through that span as code calls for (at least back in the day, and maybe it still does) or use a ridge beam the whole span, so the ends that are well supported will assist in supporting the span in the middle.

This is if there will be a snow load on the roof. If not, maybe the beam could be eliminated, but gravity will still have a factor in how this all works.

Comment: It's a 10' shed. That's _massive_ overkill. :)

Comment: Isnt the ridge 16 ft? Besides that the loft is below the top plate a good bit.

Comment: Yes, but the unsupported wall section is very short and the rafter span is shorter. The loft offset doesn't concern me for such a tiny structure.

Comment: Collar ties _at least_ 32" apart, or _at most_? It seems that 1 collar tie would meet the _at least_ criteria, and that doesn't seem like it'd be enough.

Comment: @FreeMan , I see the code did change. It appears that 4' spacing is now ok. So it seems only 1 would be needed to keep it to code, and not need a ridge beam. A note to the OP, I would still use a ridge beam, unless you change the framing at the loft to continuous studs, and set the floor joists on a let in ledger.